# http_head() not recognized by the interpreter?

Tags: php

PHP does not recognize this function:

```
http_head()
```

From the [http_head reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-head.php):

> (PECL pecl_http >= 0.1.0)

I don't know what this means:

But I used `phpversion()` to verify I'm running:

> 5.2.17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you have to install the [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/) extension [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http), version 0.1.0 or superior.

If a function is native to php, the version requirement specify PHP; eg for the function [lcfirst()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php)

```
(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)
```

Comment: So how do I do that, I have a simple godaddy like web server.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: is it called "mutualised hosting", "shared hosting" or similar ? If yes then you cannot install your own extensions. You might be able to load then with the [dl()](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) function, but that is out of scope of this question and you should ask about it on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Its not bundled with php, it is a PECL extension.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php):

> This PECL extension is not bundled with PHP

Information for installing this PECL extension may be found in the manual chapter titled [Installation of PECL extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php).

.